# Simple count visitors for front page for Joomla

Tags: google-analytics, joomla, statistics, analytics

We have a website with Joomla and we want to put a simple counter for visitors in front page of website, just the number of visitors. I use stat counter but the problem is that I can’t see all the previous visitors and this is a serious problem. I use from the first time the analytics (Google Analytics) but I didn’t find any simple (just the number) counter.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: "can't see all the previous visitors" - what do you expect from a _simple_ counter? What's stopping you from using Stat Counter and Google Analytics?

Comment: When I say simple I mean the result can only show the number of visitors so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors/2519?qh=YTozOntpOjA7czo3OiJjb3VudGVyIjtpOjE7czo4OiJjb3VudGVycyI7aToyO3M6OToiY291bnRlcidzIjt9) or [this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors/6533?qh=YTozOntpOjA7czo3OiJjb3VudGVyIjtpOjE7czo4OiJjb3VudGVycyI7aToyO3M6OToiY291bnRlcidzIjt9) for example. Just have a look at the [extension directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=counter) of Joomla.

Comment: The problem with this counters is they don't use google analytics and I lose all my previous number of visitors.